# Invalid detail when put events to amazon EventBridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I am having a hard time trying to figure where my json is invalid. When I try to put this event through EventBridge it fails.

Using AWS CLI to put the event:

```
aws events put-events --entries file://myevent.json
```

Event:

```
[
    {
        "Detail": "{\"Transaction\":{\"Hash\":\"0x00e19340c91cb32a2b80df126816f8ddc7fc5420a620ae6956cb743c67c48ac5\",\"Blockhash\":\"0x84daaa9a25783e9788aaba2c3b4160a30d1f8c978918d122aab6bede54fefe15\",\"Fromaddress\":\"0xb89eb49bc337d2bfaee360ec63ad606b6788ceb2\",\"Toaddress\":\"0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7\",\"TransactionIndex\":114,\"Gas\":200000,\"GasPrice\":37000000000,\"Nonce\":170263,\"R\":\"0xbba837f13cf1b649b2ecb0b03e85b2b447996cea5c357fe93c8e6d9d9977c31\",\"S\":\"0x1b2cf80f1fe850f1d0987bfd5e0ef981a54dbf169e3d5a573b1d4ae4374e8b15\",\"V\":0,\"Value\":0,\"Type\":0,\"Input\":\"0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000000dda2dc33eb6587af234e804f8d100c0bbe493e80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002160ec0\",\"AccessList\":\"null\",\"BlockNumber\":13320237,\"BlockNumberNavigation\":{\"Number\":13320237,\"Hash\":\"0x84daaa9a25783e9788aaba2c3b4160a30d1f8c978918d122aab6bede54fefe15\",\"BaseFeePerGas\":35599187662,\"Difficulty\":9004952891244638,\"Extradata\":\"0x65746865726d696e652d617369612d6561737432\",\"Gaslimit\":30000000,\"GasUsed\":19733780,\"Logsbloom\":\"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\",\"Miner\":\"0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8\",\"Mixhash\":\"0x744604ca511ece27d32fc7032f89bac7b35bebc9eb6ca74cd472024be5c996b3\",\"Nonce\":\"0x5d878b54f4d2ac5c\",\"Parenthash\":\"0x303fe0298f744d9ec665beae61cd61059a5b24e1791f3a8c8040d6c59bda1817\",\"Receiptsroot\":\"0x2b2849bd1e18951e72eebfb963872feb00088a1e98fea4c6d68149e6a83faf78\",\"Sha3uncles\":\"0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347\",\"Size\":36242,\"Stateroot\":\"0xf9018eebfd7515c0e6de3dc336347a56bbc74def66fc9774197257d512ea7222\",\"Timestamp\":1632912834,\"Totaldifficulty\":31491342945860289167290,\"Transactionsroot\":\"0x5852b042fa7dafc60e2f01056ae9660f84b22f8d8eb231b77a04f12e76a03800\",\"Uncles\":[],\"Transactioncount\":122},\"Receipt\":{\"Transactionhash\":\"0x00e19340c91cb32a2b80df126816f8ddc7fc5420a620ae6956cb743c67c48ac5\",\"Blockhash\":\"0x84daaa9a25783e9788aaba2c3b4160a30d1f8c978918d122aab6bede54fefe15\",\"Blocknumber\":13320237,\"Transactionindex\":114,\"Cumulativegasused\":13086616,\"Effectivegasprice\":37000000000,\"Gasused\":63197,\"Fromaddress\":\"0xb89eb49bc337d2bfaee360ec63ad606b6788ceb2\",\"Toaddress\":\"0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7\",\"Logsbloom\":\"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000280008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000010000000\",\"Status\":1,\"Type\":0,\"Logs\":[{\"data\":\"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002160ec0\",\"address\":\"0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7\",\"blockHash\":\"0x84daaa9a25783e9788aaba2c3b4160a30d1f8c978918d122aab6bede54fefe15\",\"transactionHash\":\"0x00e19340c91cb32a2b80df126816f8ddc7fc5420a620ae6956cb743c67c48ac5\",\"Topic0\":\"0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef\",\"Topic1\":\"0x000000000000000000000000b89eb49bc337d2bfaee360ec63ad606b6788ceb2\",\"Topic2\":\"0x0000000000000000000000000dda2dc33eb6587af234e804f8d100c0bbe493e8\",\"LogIndex\":298,\"logIndex\":\"0x12a\",\"ReceiptId\":\"0x00e19340c91cb32a2b80df126816f8ddc7fc5420a620ae6956cb743c67c48ac5\"}]}}}",
        "DetailType": "custom-detail",
        "EventBusName": "test-bus-lambda",
        "Resources": [],
        "Source": "My.Application",
        "Time": "2022-10-12T20:30:31.2194143-03:00"
    }
]
```

Error:

```
{
    "FailedEntryCount": 1,
    "Entries": [
        {
            "ErrorCode": "MalformedDetail",
            "ErrorMessage": "Detail is malformed."
        }
    ]
}
```

I unescaped the detail using [this website](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html#before-output) and validated it using [this tool](https://jsonlint.com/). All looks good but aws keeps returning Malformed Json. What is even more weird is that if I unescape the detail and put it using AWS Console it works.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the json parser used by AWS EventBridge can't handle long numbers like `BigInteger` we use in c#. When I removed those it worked.